# x509anchor error with entourage

Tags: macos, entourage

I use Enourage 2008 for Mac OS X 10.5.8

When I try to send a Mail with Entourage it shows following error.

> ERROR
>
> Entourage cannot find the server.
>   Verify the server information is
>   entered correctly in the Account
>   Settings, and that your DNS settings
>   in the Network pane of System
>   Preferences are correct.
>
> EXPLANATION
>
> Mail could not be sent.
>
> Account name: "mymailaccount"
>
> Error: -3176

When I go to console and look what my mac has been doing I see a bunch of theses lines

> 2010/01/09 11:06:21 PM
>   /Applications/Microsoft Office
>   2008/Microsoft
>   Entourage.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft
>   Entourage[1708] Warning: accessing
>   obsolete X509Anchors.

I just know that Entourage is accessing the false file path to the certificates and gives this error.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the Answer finally:

Entourage 2004 doesn't manage to find the certificates on Mac OS X 10.5 because they have been made obsolete.

> As it turns out, the X509Anchors file,
>   as of Leopard, has been made obsolete
>   - but not entirely... It can (and is) still read from, but cannot be written
>   to - at least not with any GUI
>   interface like Apple Keychain or
>   Microsoft Cert Manager.
>
> As Entourage looks at this X509Anchors
>   file for the Root Certificate and not
>   in the new
>   SystemCA/RootCertificates.keychain
>   files, of course it's not going to
>   find it! This also explains why people
>   that upgraded rather than fresh

Source: http://www.entourage.mvps.org/faq_topic/leopard.html